# Solution/ argument verification of a question related to product topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

This question is part of my assignment in topology and I am not sure whether I am thinking along the right lines for the solution.

> Let {${X_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda} $} be an indexed family of sets , let $\beta \in \Lambda$ , and let $A_\beta \subseteq X_\beta$ . Prove that $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(A_\beta)= \prod_{\alpha\in \Lambda} B_\alpha$ , where $B_\beta =A_\beta $ and $B_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\neq \beta $.

I think that there is not much to prove as inverse image of $A_\beta$ under projection is given by $X_\alpha  \times ... A_\beta \times ...X_\alpha $.

So, i think it was trivial.

Am i right? In case I am wrong kindly outline correct method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, I see this as trivial, but if you want a formal demonstration:

It is clear that $\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda}B_\alpha$ as you defined is contained in $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(A_{\beta})$, now suppose that $\pi_{\beta}((x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in\Lambda})\in A_{\beta}$, then $x_{\beta}\in A_{\beta}$ so $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\in\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda}B_{\alpha}$, and we have the doble inclusion.